# wp_list_categories() Exclude All Categories Except One

Tags: posts, menus, filters, categories

Is there a way to exclude all categories except one? I want to show a category and it's sub-categories as a dropdown menu, but the admin might add more subcategories to it so I don't want to limit what they can put in there by just including unique ID's.

So I want to exclude all categories except 1 and it's subcategories. Is this possible with wp_list_categories()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `exclude` parameter in the [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories). That should remove the selected categories and their descendants.

**EDIT:** Must be getting late; this almost the opposite of what you wanted. To only include one category term in a drop-down menu (and all of its descendants), you can use `child_of`.

Comment: Right but if the admin adds more categories and sub categories I would then have to go in and exclude their specific ID everytime. I'm trying to find something flexible.

Comment: You said you want to exclude all categories except 1... If you want to include only specific categories (i.e. pre-defined ones that a client hasn't added, you'll want `include` instead.)

Comment: If he uses 'include', does he have to include children IDs as well?

Comment: Yes, or he could use your solution; I don't think there's an automatic way of doing it. But if he just want's to show a category term and all its subcategories then he can just use the `child_of`.

Answer (score 0):

Theres possibly a better way of doing this, but this should work :

```
 $the_terms = get_terms( 'category', 'child_of=<replace with parent id>' );

 $included_terms = array('<replace with parent id>' );

 if( $the_terms )
 {
      foreach( $the_terms as $the_term )
           $included_terms[] = $the_term->term_id;
 }

 sort( $included_terms );

 wp_list_categories(
      'include' => $included_terms
 );
```

This way will make sure you don't have to update the list of IDs